# How can I plot a plane in matlab that is perpendicular to a known line and passes through another know point?

Tags: matlab, plane

I have a known line (green) that is formed by the two end points (blue point and black star). I wish to plot a plane that is perpendicular to this vector and also passes through a third point (the red one). I don't know where to start.

Here is a picture to illustrate the information I already have:

[image: image with current information]

Here is the code I am using. I am stuck both mathematically and in Matlab. I have obtained the coeffiecients of the plane but then I am not sure how to plot it.

```
plot3(x1,y1,z1,'.b','MarkerSize',10) %Blue point
hold on
plot3(x2,y2,z2,'kp','MarkerSize',6,'MarkerFaceColor','k') %Black star
plot3(point_x,point_y,point_z,'.r','MarkerSize',14) %Red point
plot3([x1 x2],[y1 y2],[z1 z2],'g') %Green line

A=x1-x2;
B=y1-y2;
C=z1-z2;

D=-A*point_x-B*point_y-C*point_z;
```

Comment: This sounds more like a [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com) question than a programming one... are you stuck generating the formula for the plane or plotting a plane with a given formula?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show the equation. Then, preferably add what you've already tried to code, i.e. your (non-working) code, a [mcve].

Comment: @Wolfie I actually think my problem is both

Comment: The maths comes before the programming, posts on stackoverflow should be about programming, so we can assist you if you have _specific_ implementation issues, but you might want to ask on maths.stackexchange (or elsewhere) to establish what you actually want to plot first.

Answer (score 0):

The following script solves your question.

If I find a way to attach compact MATLAB script to this answer I will readily make the script available.

If you send me an email I will send back the MATLAB script.

General plane equation `a*X + b*Y + c*Z + d = 0`

**1. `P1` Plane containing all 3 input points**

generate random points `p1` `p2` `p3`, if all aligned move one point

```
clear all;close all;clc

p1=randi([-10 10],1,3)
p2=randi([-10 10],1,3)
p3=randi([-10 10],1,3)

hf1=figure(1)
ax1=gca
hold(ax1,'on')
grid on
plot3(ax1,p1(1),p1(2),p1(3),'*r','MarkerSize',10)
plot3(ax1,p2(1),p2(2),p2(3),'*g','MarkerSize',10)
plot3(ax1,p3(1),p3(2),p3(3),'*b','MarkerSize',10)

% show X Y Z axes
plot3([-10 10],[0 0],[0 0],'--r','LineWidth',.5)
plot3([0 0],[-10 10],[0 0],'--r','LineWidth',.5)
plot3([0 0],[0 0],[-10 10],'--r','LineWidth',.5)
```

calculate plane `P1` coefficients `a` `b` `c` `d`

```
p123=[p1; p2; p3]
mP=mean(p123,1)
abc = null(p123 - mP)
d =10*( -p123(1,:)*abc) % d already amplified
```

check, should be all null

```
p123*abc + d
```

amplify coefficients

```
a=10*abc(1)
b=10*abc(2)
c=10*abc(3)
```

generate mesh

```
x_range=[-10:.1:10];
y_range=[-10:.1:10];
% z_range=[-10:.1:10]; % no need for z range
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x_range,y_range);
```

calculating plane `P1` points

```
Z1=-1/c*(a*X+b*Y+d);
```

plotting `P1`

```
hp1=surf(X, Y, Z1)
hp1.EdgeColor='none'
```

joining `p1` `p2` `p3` points

```
plot3([p1(1) p2(1)],[p1(2) p2(2)],[p1(3) p2(3)],'c','LineWidth',3)
plot3([p1(1) p3(1)],[p1(2) p3(2)],[p1(3) p3(3)],'c','LineWidth',3)
plot3([p2(1) p3(1)],[p2(2) p3(2)],[p2(3) p3(3)],'c','LineWidth',3)
```

[image]

**2. `P2` perpendicular to `P1` containing 2 input points**

Ok, this is the plane `P1` containing all 3 input points `p1` `p2` `p3`.
Input points are coloured red green blue accordingly.

Let's say you are looking for, among the many possible perpedicular planes, one that contains `p2` for instance. Let's call this perpendicular plane `P2`.

Do not use vector `mP` ; `mP` is not normal to plane `P1`

```
quiver3(0,0,0,mP(1),mP(2),mP(3),...
    'Color','#0072BD','linewidth',5,...
    'AutoScale','on','AutoScaleFactor',1,...
    'ShowArrowHead','on','Marker','.',MarkerEdgeColor='#D95319');
```

`nP1` : normal vector to `P1`

```
nP1=[a b c]
quiver3(0,0,0,nP1(1),nP1(2),nP1(3),...
    'Color','b','linewidth',2,...
    'AutoScale','on','AutoScaleFactor',1,...
    'ShowArrowHead','on','Marker','^',MarkerEdgeColor='r');
```

`p2` : choosen point to remain common to both planes.
Now one can build vector `vP21` contained in `P1` with another one of the 3 input points

```
vP21=p2-p1

vP3=3*cross2(vP21,nP1)
vP3=3*vP3/norm(vP3)

quiver3(0,0,0,vP3(1),vP3(2),vP3(3),...
    'Color','b','linewidth',2,...
    'AutoScale','on','AutoScaleFactor',1,...
    'ShowArrowHead','on','Marker','^',MarkerEdgeColor='r');

a2=vP3(1)
b2=vP3(2)
c2=vP3(3)

d2=-sum(vP3.*p2)

Z2=-1/c2*(a2*X+b2*Y+d2); 

% P2 : plane perpendicular to P1 containing chosen point p2 and p1
hp2=surf(X, Y, Z2)
hp2.EdgeColor='none'
```

[image]

**3. Perpendicular plane containing 1 input point**

And here one could argue that plane `P2` contains point `p2` indeed but also contains another of the input points, and that the resulting perpendicular plane should only contain the chosen input point `p2` excluding `p1` `p3`.

To only keep `p2` let's rotate `P2` an arbitrary angle, obtaining plane `P3` another perpendicular plane to `P1`, among many possible `P1` perpendicular planes, containing `p2`.

```
% chosing a random point contained in P1
ap=randi([-10 10],1,2)
p6=[ap(1) ap(2) -1/c*(a*ap(1)+b*ap(2)+d)]

plot3(ax1,p6(1),p6(2),p6(3),'*y','MarkerSize',10)

vP26=p2-p6

vP4=3*cross2(vP26,nP1)
vP4=3*vP4/norm(vP4)

quiver3(0,0,0,vP4(1),vP4(2),vP4(3),...
    'Color','b','linewidth',2,...
    'AutoScale','on','AutoScaleFactor',1,...
    'ShowArrowHead','on','Marker','^',MarkerEdgeColor='r');

a3=vP4(1)
b3=vP4(2)
c3=vP4(3)

d3=-sum(vP4.*p2)

Z3=-1/c3*(a3*X+b3*Y+d3); 

% P3 : plane perpendicular to P1 containing chosen point p2 and p1
hp3=surf(X, Y, Z3)
hp3.EdgeColor='none'
```

[image]

**4. support functions / scripts :**

4.1. Paolo deLeva's `cross2` available here

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8782-vector-algebra-for-arrays-of-any-size-with-array-expansion-enabled

4.2. John d'Erico's script showing compact method to go from plane points to plane coefficients in MATLAB stype; no need for a single `for` loop. Available here

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/723053-solve-plane-equation-with-3-points-and-additional-condition

I have amplified/attenuated supprt vectors in a convenient way, for instance I just multipled x10 all `a` `b` `c` `d` so that produced coefficients are not liliput-only values.

**6. Additional Comments :**

There are many perpendicular planes, even just keeping 1 input point. With additional input request like a rotation angle or a 4th point then the solution would be unique.

If you find this solution useful, would you please be so kind to mark it as correct answer?

Thanks for reading my solution.

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/723053-solve-plane-equation-with-3-points-and-additional-condition

Comment: Thanks! @John BG Your answer is truly appreciated, but if I am not mistaken the plane is not perpendicular to the line formed by p1 and p2. Is it possible to do that?